# IPN for PayPal sending empty string

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

using this code, obtained from another stackoverflow post, to implement a listener page for PayPal's IPN:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Using the IPN Simulator (Express Checkout) to send the test sale data.

$raw_post_data returns "" (empty string)....EVERY TIME.

I also tried to read the $_POST directly into an array, however, the $_POST is empty upon arrival from PayPal...EVERY TIME.

I called the company hosting the site and they are not blocking $_POST from PayPal.

I called PayPal and they basically told me to Google the problem and/or visit developer.paypal.com.  I did and it directs me here.

I have been at this for two straight days and ready to jump out my window.  Any solution/help you may provide would be sincerely appreciated.  I've exhausted option/solution I found online and don't have anyone I can call.

Comment: Try something like omnipay-paypal. See if that still returns empty string. https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

Comment: negative, ghost rider.  is there a version of php that is required for file_get_contents()?

Comment: I'm checking log file I create and PayPal is sending the stream.  it's just that when it gets to the listener page, string is empty.  ??? totally baffled here ???

Comment: fixed.  Un-friggin-believable....The file_get_contents() was working fine the whole time.  The issue was case sensitive calls made to the database.  The data was there but couldn't be displayed.  Feeling foolish....very foolish.